# An easy way to change validation-error messages in django-trunk?

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there an easy way to change the validation message that occurs for something like `auth_views.password_reset` without going into django's trunk?

A message such as "That e-mail address doesn't have an associated user account. Are you sure you've registered?" I'd like to change to "There is no user account. Please click here to register." What would be the easiest way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message, like all of the messages from Django core, are internationalized, so you can override the text of selected messages without modifying core files by creating a translation file with higher precedence (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-translations)

1. Create a new file in your project like locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
2. Search for the message text you want to override in django/conf/locales/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
3. Copy and paste the lines that define that message into your own translation file
4. Put the text you want to replace it with in the `msgstr` line (not the `msgid` line)
5. Run django-admin.py compilemessages
6. Make sure USE_I18N and USE_L10N settings are set correctly

The message should now be replaced with what you want.